# Persisting data between app launches with Expo & React Native

Tags: react-native, expo, asyncstorage

Here's my `App.js`, everything else is as standard/simple as I can get it.

```
import React from 'react';
import { AsyncStorage, Text, View } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {

    console.log("Fetching data")
    AsyncStorage.getItem('@MySuperStore:key', (value) => {
      console.log("Fetched data: ", value)
      if(value == null) {
        console.log("Writing data!")
        AsyncStorage.setItem('@MySuperStore:key', 'data', () => {
          console.log("Wrote data!")
        })
      }
    })

    return(
    <View>
      <Text>Hello, ReplIt</Text>
    </View>
    );
  }
}
```

The fetched `value` is always `null`.

I've tried this both locally and on ReplIt. In all cases, the data does not persist across app loads; I always see:

```
Fetching data
Fetched data:  null
Writing data!
Wrote data!
```

What am I doing wrong? Do I have an incorrect assumption about how Expo interacts with the persistent storage? AFAIK, `AsyncStorage` is supposed to save stuff to the device; so I can close and re-open the app and have the data persist.

Comment: Are you using ReplIt? That's probably the reason.

Comment: "I've tried this both locally and on ReplIt"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPD:** i just realized your code worked as expected... probably it is replit issue as mentioned in comment.

Avoid any requests and async calls in `render` method, because it could be called may times depending on how props or state changing. Better put all related code into `componentDidMount` as it is recommended in [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount). It will be called only once when component mounted.

Not sure why your code dodnt worked for you, callbacks are allowed for `AsyncStorage`, however wait works just fine for me:

```js
import React from "react";
import { AsyncStorage, Text, View } from "react-native";

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      storedValue: null
    };
  }
  async componentDidMount() {
    let storedValue = await AsyncStorage.getItem("@MySuperStore:key");
    console.log("Fetched data: ", storedValue);
    if (storedValue == null) {
      console.log("Writing data!");
      storedValue = await AsyncStorage.setItem("@MySuperStore:key", "data");
    }
    this.setState({
      storedValue
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { storedValue } = this.state;
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>Hello, ReplIt</Text>
        <Text>This is Stored Value, '{storedValue}'</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Yep, that did it. I confused myself a bit between Repl.It and locally, since I didn't do a complete code replace locally, but this works.

Answer (score 2):

give these a try. AsyncStorage is a Javascript Promise based method.

```
AsyncStorage.getItem('@MySuperStore:key')
.then(value => console.log(value))
```

or

```
value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@MySuperStore:key');
console.log(value);
```